# Is there a programatic way of knowing when DOM updates by jQuery have been completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

For example:

```
var $myContainer = $('#myContainer');
$myContainer.html(someHtml);
var width = $myContainer.height();
var height = $myContainer.height();
```

If #myContainer was an empty div, width and height would still be zero.  A solution is to use a timeout:

```
var $myContainer = $('#myContainer');
$myContainer.html(someHtml);
setTimeout(function () {
    var width = $myContainer.height();
    var height = $myContainer.height();
}, 500);
```

However, I don't like the magic number in there.  What if its a really slow browser?  Is there any reliable cross browser method available to tell me when the browser has rendered the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `0` for the timeout, reliably. It won't actually be 0ms, you understand, most browsers will make it at least 5 or 10, but just the act of yielding to the browser is sufficient.

That said, I'm [not immediately finding](http://jsbin.com/oqijo4) a browser that doesn't get the (new) height right immediately, without a yield (even IE6!). But I wouldn't be surprised if, depending on markup and such, there were one...

Comment: Today I went back and tested the timeout code with a zero, and it worked.  I put this down to this week having a new work computer, which is much faster.  With my old machine I needed a timeout of at least 100ms.  Do you have a fast machine?

Comment: @Sprintstar: Yes, but I don't think it a difference for functions like `height`. Ajax (referenced in other comments) would be a *totally* different matter, the only reliable way to handle that is the callback. I've used the `setTimeout` trick with `0` on single-core Atom netbooks. The above updates immediately (without even waiting for the timeout) on Safari on my phone, which is probably my slowest machine (not that it's *slow*). The first step would be to find a browser were the height didn't immediately update (I haven't yet), and then to see if anything above `0` were required.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like a hack but might work: Add a script element to the DOM as the last element. All browsers should execute that after all the other elements have "settled."

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ajax?

So you can use jQuery 'load'.

```
var $myContainer = $('#myContainer');
$myContainer.load('/url/for/someHtml', function(){
  var width = $myContainer.height();
  var height = $myContainer.height();
});
```

Comment: I am using ajax, but wasn't using load (I am now where possible).  However I am now unable to test this (see my other comment).  It uses the same innerHTML method as .html(), so I am not sure this is going to be any different.

Comment: If you're using ajax I see no reason to didn't use .load(), that gives you an immediate callback after load the content. If I uderstand your intention.